# how to create form in dashboard which should be reflected at front end?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on word press project. My task is to create a module where user can create a feedback form in admin panel. And this feedback form is going to be reflected in front end, so that all user can fill it.
Please tell me what is the exact way to achieve this.

I Don't want code, just a guidance regarding plugins or wordpress api which can be helpful for me in this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).

In the admin Panel you can create Forms that can be inserted in your Pages with shortcode.